# How to abstract JQuery animate method

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, bind

Below I have a working example of an abstraction of the jQuery animate method I did and it works fine. However, if you noticed In the function *ani(){}*  I hard coded in the DOM element class. I want to replace the hard coded DOM element with the 'this' keyword so I can use it in other places. When I try to do this it doesn't work, I tried experimenting with bind() and nothing I did remedied this.

Code below:
https://jsfiddle.net/u28fhf77/2/

---

```
$(".item").hover(function() {

    ani("+=50", "+=50")



}, function() {

    ani("-=50", "-=50")


});


function ani(val1, val2) {
    var height = val1;
    var width = val2
    $(".item").animate({    // Hardcoded 'item' but want 'this'
        height: height,
        width: width
    }, 200);
}
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fairly simple to convert by adding an extra argument for the element.

```
$(".item").hover(function () {
    ani(this, "+=50", "+=50");

}, function () {
    ani(this, "-=50", "-=50");

});


function ani(elem, val1, val2) {        
    $(elem).animate({ 
        height: val1,
        width: val2
    }, 200);
}
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/guxu73tj/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thank you when the time limit is up I will check the answer